# angular 6 component property use

Tags: angular, angular-components

I was looking into angular 6+ code and I am not sure what is this piece code **#testPicker**  ? what is this syntax and why is it used? My question is not specific to this code but generally what is  use of #testPicker in this component.

```
 <app-name-picker [readonly]="isValidForm()" [value]="selectedUser" (selectionChange)="selectUser($event)" #testPicker></app-name-picker>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In angular the Hashtag is referred to as a **Template Reference Variable.**
It is usually used to provide access to a component (and its data) from other components or from within a parent component's code.

**From other components, Eg:**

```html
<input #phone placeholder="phone number">
<button (click)="callPhone(phone.value)">Call</button>
```

**From parent component code, using ViewChild, Eg:**

```
@ViewChild('phone') phoneNumber;
ngAfterViewInit(){
  callPhoneNumber(this.phoneNumber.nativeElement.value);
}
```

Further Reading and Reference: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-

Comment: Template reference variables are initialized after ngAfterViewInit.

Answer (score 1):

We use this declarative approach to have opportunity to access elements in the view directly.

For example:

```
<input #myname>

@ViewChild('myname') input;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.input.nativeElement.value);
}
```

[Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-)

Answer (score 0):

here hashtag mean reference of that html, so giving Template Reference Variable allow you to access that DOM to Component.

```
@ViewChild('divReference') divReference;

ngAfterViewInIt(){
console.log(this.divReference);
}
```

it is like **document.getElementById('divReference')** in Java Script.